# cshtml passing model value to javascript function

Tags: javascript, razor, model-view-controller

Here I have an view model

```
public class SimpleModel {
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

And I passing the my model value,

```
...
var myModel = new SimpleModel() {
    Id = "1234";
    Name = "Dean";
};
return View(..., myModel);
```

Here the problem I faced, I trying to passing the value to a javascript after pressing a button or link, but it fail to work, I doubt did my model contain the value and I double check by display it out, it seems it contain value.

Here the part of my code

```
...
<a href="javascript:functionA(@Model.Name)">Call Function</a>
<span>@Model.Name</span>
...
```

If I remove the `@Model.Name` parameter, it work perfectly. Is there way to fix this? or I did wrong on the part I passing the parameter.

Error I get is

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
```

Any help to this will be appreciated and sorry if I explain the situation bad. Thanks.

Comment: You need to quote the value `href="javascript:functionA('@Model.Name')"`

Comment: @Jasen that what is missing, thanks for the help, save my days, thanks

Answer (score 0):

dude, dont use ; when declaring, this is C# code and you should do it like this:

```
var myModel = new SimpleModel() {
    Id = "1234",
    Name = "Dean"
};
```

and i believe this is C# not a javascript, this is ASP.NET, you put in wrong tag